# Batch Insert In Cassandra using Apache Spark hanging and context not getting closed when triggered from a Web Ser

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am a new to spark . I am trying to insert csv files into cassandra table using spark-cassandra connector as below:
The files are in Hdfs and I am getting the Paths of all files and for each path I call a method which does converts the csv data to corressponding cassandra data types and creates a prepared statement binds the data to the prepared statement and adds it to a batch. Finally I execute the batch when its 1000. 
Key Points 
1. I am using Apache Cassandra 2.1.8 and Spark 1.5 
2. I read the Csv files using Spark Context 
3. I am using the com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector to create a Session with Cassandra.

I have 9 Files , each files data goes to a table in cassandra. Every Things works fine All inserts are happening as expected and the job gets completed when I submit the jar on spark submit.

The problem I am facing is When the same Jar is invoked through a web-service (web service calls the script to invoke the jar) One of the files data doesn’t get inserted and the spark context doesn’t stop due to which the jobs is forever running.

When I insert 4 files or 5 files everything works fine even through the web-service. But all together it hanging and I get 10 records less in one of the tables and context doesn’t stop.

Its strange because when I am submitting the jar on the spark submit directly everything works fine and through the web service I face this issue , Its strange bcz even the web-service submits the job to the same spark submit.

Here is my code

```
package com.pz.loadtocassandra;



 import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
 import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
 import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function;

import com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement;
import com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement;
import com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraRow;
import com.pz.shared.UnicodeBOMInputStream;
import com.pz.shared.fileformat.Header;
import com.pz.shared.mr.fileformat.MRFileFormats.CSVInputFormat;
import com.pz.shared.mr.fileformat.MRFileFormats.TextArrayWritable;


 public class LoadToCassandra {

public static final String STUDYID = "STUDYID";
public static final String PROJECTNAME = "PROJECTNAME";
public static final String FILEID = "FILEID";
public static int count = 0;
public static final String FILE_SERPERATOR = "/";
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoadToCassandra.class.getName());
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String propFileLoc = args[0];
        String hdfsHome = args[1];
        String hdfs_DtdXmlPath = args[2];
        String hdfs_NormalizedDataPath = args[3];

        run(propFileLoc, hdfsHome,     hdfs_DtdXmlPath,hdfs_NormalizedDataPath);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error occur in FileHandler.", exception);
    }
}

public static void run(String propFileLoc, String hdfsHome,
        String hdfs_DtdXmlPath, String hdfs_NormalizedDataPath) {
    JavaSparkContext ctx = null;
    FileSystem hadoopFs = null;
    try {

        PropInitialize.initailizeConfig(propFileLoc);
        //setting spark context
        ctx = setSparkContext(propFileLoc);
        ParseDtdXml.parseDTDXML(hdfsHome, hdfs_DtdXmlPath);
        Configuration configuration = setHadoopConf();
        hadoopFs = getHadoopFs(hdfsHome, configuration);
        FileStatus[] fstat = hadoopFs.listStatus(new Path(hdfs_NormalizedDataPath));
        //Getting the csv paths
        Path[] paths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(fstat);
        log.info("PATH.size - " + paths.length);
        for (Path path : paths) {
            log.info("path is : "+path.toString());
            loadToCassandra(propFileLoc, path, configuration,hdfsHome, ctx);
        }


    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "run method", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        log.info("finally ");
        if (ctx!= null) {
            ctx.stop();
            System.out.println("SC Stopped");
        }
        if (hadoopFs != null) {
            try {
                hadoopFs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "run method", e);
            }
        }
    }
}



// input : 1. String hdfs home ,
// 2. Configuration hadoop conf object
// returns : hadoop File System object
private static FileSystem getHadoopFs(String hdfsHome,
        Configuration configuration) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    return FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfsHome), configuration);

}

// input : no inputs
// process : sets hadoop config parameters
// output : retuns hadoop conf object
private static Configuration setHadoopConf() throws IOException,
        URISyntaxException {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setBoolean("csvFileFormat.encoded.flag", true);
    configuration.set("csvinputformat.token.delimiter", ",");
    return configuration;

}

// input : string Properties File Location
// process : creates and sets the configurations of spark context
// retuns : JavaSparkContext object with configurations set to it.
private static JavaSparkContext setSparkContext(String propFileLoc) {
    PropInitialize.initailizeConfig(propFileLoc);
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.set("spark.serializer",
            "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer");
    conf.setAppName("Loading Data");
    conf.setMaster(PropInitialize.spark_master);
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host",
            PropInitialize.cassandra_hostname);
    conf.setJars(PropInitialize.external_jars);
    return new JavaSparkContext(conf);

}

private static void loadToCassandra(String propFileLoc, Path sourceFileHdfsPath,
        Configuration hadoopConf, String hdfsHome,JavaSparkContext ctx) {
    System.out.println("File :: " + sourceFileHdfsPath.toString());
    FileSystem hadoopFs = null;
    PropInitialize.initailizeConfig(propFileLoc);
    String cassKeyspaceName = PropInitialize.cass_keyspace_name;
    log.info("entered here for file "+sourceFileHdfsPath.toString());

    final String strInputFileName = StringUtils.split(
            sourceFileHdfsPath.getName(), "#")[0].toLowerCase();
    final String strTableNameInCass = StringUtils.split(
            sourceFileHdfsPath.getName(), "-")[0].split("#")[1]
            .toLowerCase();

    final String strSourceFilePath = sourceFileHdfsPath.toString();

    try {
        hadoopFs = getHadoopFs(hdfsHome, hadoopConf);

        //getting the cassandra connection using spark conf
        final CassandraConnector connector = getCassandraConnection(ctx);

         final JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassTableObj=getCassTableObj(ctx,cassKeyspaceName,strTableNameInCass);

        final Map<String, List<String>> tabColMapWithColTypes1 = ParseDtdXml.tabColMapWithColTypes;

        final String headersUpdated;
        final String headers;

        UnicodeBOMInputStream ubis = new UnicodeBOMInputStream(
                hadoopFs.open(sourceFileHdfsPath));
        Header CsvHeader = Header.getCSVHeader(ubis, ",");
        if (!strTableNameInCass.equalsIgnoreCase("PCMASTER")) {

            String fString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < CsvHeader.size() - 1; i++) {
                fString = fString + CsvHeader.get(i).ColumnName + ",";
            }
            fString = fString
                    + CsvHeader.get(CsvHeader.size() - 1).ColumnName;

            headers = fString; // StringUtils.join(stringArr.toString(),",");

            headersUpdated = strTableNameInCass.toUpperCase() + "ID,"
                    + headers;

        } else {

            String[] stringArr = new String[CsvHeader.size()];
            String fString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < CsvHeader.size() - 1; i++) {
                // stringArr[i] = CsvHeader.get(i).ColumnName;
                fString = fString + CsvHeader.get(i).ColumnName + ",";
            }
            fString = fString
                    + CsvHeader.get(CsvHeader.size() - 1).ColumnName;
            headers = StringUtils.join(stringArr.toString(), ",");
            headersUpdated = fString;

        }

        ubis.close();


        //Reading the file using spark context
        JavaPairRDD<LongWritable, TextArrayWritable> fileRdd = ctx
                .newAPIHadoopFile(strSourceFilePath, CSVInputFormat.class,
                        LongWritable.class, TextArrayWritable.class,
                        hadoopConf);


        final long recCount = fileRdd.count();



        final String[] actCols = headersUpdated.split(",");

        final LinkedHashMap<Object, String> mapOfColNameAndType = new LinkedHashMap<Object, String>();
        final List<String> colNameAndType = tabColMapWithColTypes1
                .get(strTableNameInCass.toUpperCase());

        for (int i = 0; i < actCols.length; i++) {

            if (colNameAndType.contains(actCols[i] + " " + "text")) {
                int indexOfColName = colNameAndType.indexOf(actCols[i]
                        + " " + "text");

                mapOfColNameAndType.put(i,
                        colNameAndType.get(indexOfColName).split(" ")[1]);

            } else if (colNameAndType
                    .contains(actCols[i] + " " + "decimal")) {
                int indexOfColName = colNameAndType.indexOf(actCols[i]
                        + " " + "decimal");
                mapOfColNameAndType.put(i,
                        colNameAndType.get(indexOfColName).split(" ")[1]);
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }

        //creates the query for prepared statement
        final String makeStatement = makeSt(cassKeyspaceName,
                strTableNameInCass, actCols);
        final long seqId1 = cassTableObj.count();


        //calling map on the fileRdd 
        JavaRDD<String> data = fileRdd.values().map(
                new Function<TextArrayWritable, String>() {
                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    Session session;
                    boolean isssession = false;
                    PreparedStatement statement;
                    BatchStatement batch;
                    int lineCount = 0;

                    long seqId = seqId1;

                    /*for each line returned as an TextArrayWritable convert each cell the corresponding
                     * bind the data to prepared statement
                     * add it to batch
                     */
                    @Override
                    public String call(TextArrayWritable tup)
                            throws Exception {
                        seqId++;
                        lineCount++;

                        log.info("entered here 3 for file "+strSourceFilePath.toString());
                        String[] part = tup.toStrings();


                        Object[] parts = getDataWithUniqueId(
                                strTableNameInCass, part);


                        //For each file
                        //Creates the session
                        //creates the PreparedStatement
                        if (!isssession) {
                            session = connector.openSession();
                            statement = session.prepare(makeStatement);
                            log.info("entered here 4 for file "+strSourceFilePath.toString());
                            // System.out.println("statement :" +
                            // statement);
                            isssession = true;
                            batch = new BatchStatement();
                        }

                        List<Object> typeConvData = new ArrayList<Object>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                            String type = mapOfColNameAndType.get(i);
                            try {
                                if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {

                                    typeConvData.add(parts[i]);
                                } else {

                                    // parts[i] =
                                    // parts[i].toString().replace("\"",
                                    // "");
                                    // check if the String the has to
                                    // converted to a BigDecimal is any
                                    // positive or negetive integer or not.
                                    // if its not a positive integer or
                                    // negative forcefully convert it to
                                    // zero (avoiding NumberFormatException)
                                    if (!((String) parts[i])
                                            .matches("-?\\d+")) {
                                        parts[i] = "0";
                                    }
                                    long s = Long
                                            .valueOf((String) parts[i]);
                                    typeConvData.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(s));

                                }
                            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "loadToCass method", e);


                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "loadToCass method", e);
                            } catch (InvalidTypeException e) {
                                log.log(Level.SEVERE, "loadToCass method", e);
                            }
                        }

                                                    List<Object> data = typeConvData;

                        //bind data to query
                        final BoundStatement query = statement.bind(data
                                .toArray(new Object[data.size()]));

                        //add query to batch
                        batch.add(query);
                        int count = LoadToCassandra.count;

                        //when count is 1k execute batch
                        if (count == 1000) {

                            log.info("entered here 5 for file "+strSourceFilePath.toString());
                            log.info("batch done");
                            session.execute(batch);
                            LoadToCassandra.count = 0;
                            batch = new BatchStatement();
                            return StringUtils.join(tup.toStrings());
                        }

                        //if its the last batch and its not of size 1k
                        if (lineCount == (recCount))
                            {
                            log.info("Last Batch");
                            session.executeAsync(batch);
                            log.info("entered here 6 for file "+strSourceFilePath.toString());
                            //session.execute(batch);
                            session.close();
                            log.info("Session closed");
                        }

                        LoadToCassandra.count++;
                        return StringUtils.join(tup.toStrings());
                    }

                    private Object[] getDataWithUniqueId(
                            String strTableNameInCass, String[] part) {
                        Object[] parts = null;
                        ArrayList<String> tempArraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
                        if (!strTableNameInCass
                                .equalsIgnoreCase("PCMASTER")) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
                                if (i == 0) {
                                    tempArraylist.add(0,
                                            String.valueOf(seqId));
                                }
                                tempArraylist.add(part[i]);
                            }
                            parts = tempArraylist.toArray();
                        } else {
                            parts = part;
                        }

                        return parts;
                    }

                });

        data.count();
        hadoopFs.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static JavaRDD<CassandraRow> getCassTableObj(
        JavaSparkContext ctx, String cassKeyspaceName,
        String strTableNameInCass) {
    return javaFunctions(ctx)
            .cassandraTable(cassKeyspaceName,
                    strTableNameInCass.toLowerCase());
}

private static CassandraConnector getCassandraConnection(
        JavaSparkContext ctx) {
    return CassandraConnector.apply(ctx.getConf());

}

private static String makeSt(String keyspace, String tabName,
        String[] colNames) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("INSERT INTO " + keyspace + "." + tabName + " ( ");
    List<String> vars = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < (colNames.length - 1); i++) {
        sb.append(colNames[i] + ",");
        vars.add("?");
    }
    vars.add("?");
    sb.append(colNames[colNames.length - 1] + " ) values ( "
            + StringUtils.join(vars, ",") + " ) ");

    return sb.toString();
   }}
```

Can anyone tell me what could the reason that causes this problem and how can it be resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Once you inserted your data into cassandra, call `ctx.stop()` method, it will stop spark context.

Comment: I am doing that in the finally block of the run method. But seems like when the last file calls the loadToCassandra method , It getting hanged somewhere because of which some 10 records of that last file doesn’t get inserted to a particular table and due to which context doesnt get stopped... This oli when the jar is invoked by a web service.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Can you share it?

Comment: I am not getting any exception but I can share u the logs